# ASP.NET Disable Submit button only if all controls are validated

Tags: asp.net

I need to disable the submit button, to prevent double posting.

I added the following attributes to the asp:button:

```
UseSubmitBehaviour="false" 
OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';this.value='Please wait ...'"
```

This works only if on the first click all controls of the form are valid. But if any one of the asp:RequiredFieldValidor fails, the button is disabled until the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the below code:**

```
 OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate()) { this.disabled='true';this.value='Please wait ...'}"
```

**Explanation**

`Page_ClientValidate()` This method is used for asp.net client side validation. So, if you page in client side validated then only disable your text box.